# Can a decision trees branches meet after they have split earlier?

Tags: decision-tree

[image]

When you are drawing a decision tree, are you allowed to converge again after a split earlier in the tree like the picture shows?

Comment: "It depends" based on the precise definition used - a 'true' decision tree is, well, a tree and never converges. The term for a 'converging tree' would generally be a [decision flowchart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) (such flowcharts can be expanded into non-converging decision trees because they are still stateless, the flowchart aspect allows the visual simplification).